# Jquery Animate delay even though no delay Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am encountering a problem with jquery. The problem is, I have made an animation on an ".info" div box. I want it to slide into the document and then slide out again when you deselect a button - the sliding in works fine, but when you deselect there is a delay of 20 seconds or so. I have no idea where this delay comes from. Can you help me?

The link is: http://ljensenphoto.dk/dokken/dokken.html

Javascript code (sorry for the comments - I have written these to help myself, I am obviously new to Javascript and jquery :D ):

```
  $(document).on("ready");

//to variabler - kan ændre værdien.
var selected;
var info;

//to konstante. Her definerer vi værdien af de to cirklers farver :D. Den første definerer hvilken farve cirklen skal have når der IKKE er klikket på den. Den anden definerer hvilken farve cirklen skal have, når vi har klikket på den. 
const colorNeutral = "";
const colorSelected = "#d8ff00";

//loader SVG ind i dokumentet. Det første er "selectoren", der vælger noget i DOM - HTML'en. "" = Strings. 

$("#dokkenkort").load("Dokken.svg", loadSvg);

//loader JSON ind i dokumentet

function loadSvg(){
$.getJSON("dokken.JSON", loadJSON);

}


function loadJSON(data) {
    info = data;
     $("#info g").on("click", circleClick);

}


function circleClick(event) {
    console.log("Det virker sguda!!!!");

    if (event.delegateTarget == selected) {
       console.log("Klikkede på det samme som allerede er valgt!");

        // Gør så sidste klik bliver glemt og nulstilles.
        $(selected).children().attr("fill", colorNeutral);

        //Følgende giver en ekstra attribut til en selector. 
        //$(selected).children().attr("r", 6);

        // Glemmer hvad der blev selected
        selected = null;

        $(".info").animate({top:"1000px"},500,clear);


        // Clearer info-div-boksen

        function clear(){$(".info").text("");}


    } else {
        console.log("klik på et nyt element!");
        // Disabler forrige selection.
        $(selected).children().attr("fill", colorNeutral);

        //Følgende giver en ekstra attribut til en selector. 
        //$(selected).children().attr("r", 6);

        // husker hvad der blev selected (bliver gemt i "selected" som vi defineret som en variabel øverst)!
        selected = event.delegateTarget;

        console.log(selected.id)
        // mark selected
        $(selected).children().attr("fill", colorSelected);


        // display info on selected
        showInfo();
    }

}


//udskriver teksten!

function showInfo( ) {
    // find info in info-array
    $.each(info, findSelectedInfo);
    console.log("Hey man! FindSelectedInfo");
}

function findSelectedInfo(key, value) {

    if (value.sted == selected.id) {
        console.log("Indeni if");
        $(".info").html("<h1>"+value.overskrift+"</h1>");
        $(".info").append("<p>"+value.tekst+"</p>");
        $(".info").append("<img src='"+value.billed+"' alt='"+value.sted+"'>");
    }
    $(".info").animate({top:"500px"},3000);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Best regards
Kalle Jensen.

Comment: `$(document).on("ready");` why?

Comment: Because I want it to load the .js file fully before starting running scripts. Isn't this how it's done?